# Mongoose find returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoDB document which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b99247efb6fc01dae438815"
    },
    "participants": [
        "5b758a8341ee61f049ded486",
        "5b94fb4ffb6fc01dae40eae3"
    ]
}
```

The document Schema in Mongoose is defined as such

```
var conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
});
```

I am fetching the data as such

```
var ccc = Conversation.find({participants : "5b758a8341ee61f049ded486"});
ccc.exec(function(err, conversations){
   res.status(200).json(conversations);
});
```

The problem is that I am getting an empty array response `[]`.

### I think the problem is with Schema but I can't figure out how can I make this to work.

EDIT,
If I change my Schema to the following it will work:

```
var conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    participants: [{ type: String}],
});
```

But I want to work with `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` and not `Strings` as foreign key.

Comment: Cast your participants id with ObjectId... `Conversation.find({ participants: ObjectId("5b758a8341ee61f049ded486") })`

Comment: Tried this `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b758a8341ee61f049ded486")` but still same empty array response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding Types to this line:

```
participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
```

It wont recognize the items in the array because they are strings you should have instead an object like {"$oid": "585bb0086c57cd2265b1cbd3"} so reinsert the items in you db and try again.